# Injecting style into a tested page

Tags: css, testing, automated-tests, inject, testcafe

I have an issue with the div:

```
<div id="root-hammerhead-shadow-ui" contenteditable="false" class="root-hammerhead-shadow-ui"></div>
```

which is injected by testcafe into an iframe that I'd like to test.

The iframe contains an input field and some styles which make the hammerhead div cover the iframe and input completely (width/height set to 100%) so I'm unable to use typeText with it (expect visible passes correctly).

I can fix the issue during debugging by setting the width/height of the hammerhead div to defaults, can I somehow do the same thing in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) API to manipulate DOM elements on a client. Please take a look at the following example:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `New Fixture`
    .page `https://example.com`;

test('New Test', async t => {
    const changeHammerheadDiv = ClientFunction(() => {
        const hammerHeadDiv = document.getElementById('root-hammerhead-shadow-ui');

        hammerHeadDiv.style.width =  '0';
        hammerHeadDiv.style.height = '0';
    });

    await t.switchToIframe(Selector('iframe'));
    await changeHammerheadDiv();
    await t.typeText(Selector('body').find('input'), 'qwerty');
});
```

Comment: ClientFunction is exactly what I needed, thank you!
It turned out that this div is a shadow element and I couldn't select it with getElementById so I ended up adding a simple style "#root-hammerhead-shadow-ui { width: 0; height: 0; }" to the document.